# Object fetched in the query but not include in the result

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I use spring data jpa, hibernate I have a complex structure. I search to get samples with some object fetched

```
@Entity
@IdClass(SamplingsPK.class)
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public class Samplings {

    @Id
    private int year;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer sequenceId;

    @OneToOne
    private Products product;

    @OneToOne
    private Machines machine;

    @OneToOne
    private Dimensions dimension;

    @OneToOne
    private Colors color;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "sampling", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Samples> samples = new ArrayList<>();
    ...

}

@Entity
@IdClass(SamplesPK.class)
public class Samples extends BaseEntity { 

    @Id
    private String sampleLetter;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "sampling_id", referencedColumnName = "sequenceId"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "sampling_year", referencedColumnName = "year")})
    private Samplings sampling;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "sample", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
    //@JoinColumns({
    //    @JoinColumn(name = "sampling_id", referencedColumnName = "sequenceId"),
    //    @JoinColumn(name = "sampling_year", referencedColumnName = "year")})
    private TestSamples testSamples;
    ...
}

public class SamplesPK implements Serializable {

    private SamplingsPK sampling;

    private String sampleLetter;

    public SamplesPK(SamplingsPK sampling, String sampleLetter) {
        this.sampling = sampling;
        this.sampleLetter = sampleLetter;
    }

    private SamplesPK() {

    }
}

@Entity
public class TestSamples {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "test_samples_id_seq", sequenceName = "test_samples_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "test_samples_id_seq")
    private Integer id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Samples sample;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "testSample", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Compressions compressionTest;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "testSample", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Durabilities durabilityTest;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "testSample", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Scalings scalingTest;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "testSample", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Granulometries granulometryTest;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Absorptions absorptionTest;
    ...
}
```

When I save a  new samplings, i do

```
Samplings sampling = new Samplings();
..
Samples sample = new Samples();
 ...
TestSamples testSamples = new TestSamples();
testSamples.setSample(sample);
..
sample.setTestSamples(testSamples);

samplings.addSample(sample);

samplings = samplingsRepository.save(sampling);
```

After saving, If i try to get a samples with testSample, I run this query

```
@Query(
        value = "select s from Samples s Join fetch s.sampling sp Left Join fetch sp.machine m Join fetch sp.product p Join  fetch p.productType pt Join Fetch s.testSamples",
        countQuery = "select count(s) from Samples s Join s.sampling sp Left Join  sp.machine m Join  sp.product p Join  p.productType Join s.testSamples")
public Page<Samples> findAllFullSample(Pageable pageable);
```

When I check sample, TestSamples is always null

I found a very bad workaround...

```
Page<Samples> pageSamples = samplesRepository.findAllFullSample(pageable);
List<Samples> samples = pageSamples.getContent();
for (Samples sample : samples) {
    TestSamples testSample= testSamplesRepository.findSamplesWithFullProductAndCompressionTest(sample.getSampling().getSequenceId(),sample.getSampling().getYear(), sample.getSampleLetter());
    sample.setTestSamples(testSample);
}
return pageSamples;
```

Code of the query

```
@Query(value = "select ts from TestSamples ts Join ts.sample s left Join Fetch ts.compressionTest where s.sequenceId=:id and s.year=:year and s.sampleLetter=:sampleLetter")
public TestSamples findSamplesWithFullProductAndCompressionTest(@Param("id") Integer id, @Param("year") int year, @Param("sampleLetter") String sampleLetter);
```

So why TestSample is null when I get it from Sample

Comment: try with FetchType Eager on testSamples

Comment: Goal of using fetch = FetchType.LAZY on TestSamples in Samples is to get only what i need 99%... that why i created a specific query: findAllFullSample

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your mapping is incorrect.

When I look at the Samples class is see:

```
 @OneToOne(mappedBy = "sample", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "sampling_id", referencedColumnName = "sequenceId"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "sampling_year", referencedColumnName = "year")})
    private TestSamples testSamples;
    ...
```

This looks like copy past from the sampling mapping.

You should check if you mapping is correct first.

Do you generate the tables from the mapping? If yes check if the generated tables look like expected.

Comment: having  @JoinColumns or not change nothing, all is generated from the mapping and it's ok

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is an answer as such - I tried this out against the sample classes, and example code:

```
    Samplings sampling = new Samplings();
    sampling.setYear(2018);

    Samples sample = new Samples();
    sample.setSampling(sampling);
    sample.setSampleLetter("A");

    TestSamples testSamples = new TestSamples();
    testSamples.setSample(sample);

    sample.setTestSamples(testSamples);
    sampling.addSample(sample);

    sampling = samplingsRepository.save(sampling);

    EntityManager em = ...;
    em.flush();
    em.clear();

    Pageable pageable = Pageable.unpaged();
    Page<Samples> samples = repository.findAllFullSample(pageable);

    Samples firstSampleBack = samples.getContent().get(0);
    System.out
            .println("--> testSamples=" + firstSampleBack.getTestSamples());
```

This returned the related TestSamples successfully:

```
--> testSamples=TestSamples [id=1]
```

The test commented out any other classes apart these three, including from the query, I don't know if there is something else needed to reproduce the problem you're seeing.

It seemed easiest to post that working example in full.  Perhaps this will at least provide an alternative to compare against.

https://github.com/df789/samples-query

This is against Spring Boot and an H2 in-memory database, so should run fine standalone.  E.g. `mvn clean test` is enough to see the test case above.

**Edit**

To follow up on Robert's comment below, from a bit of debugging, it looks like Hibernate compares the types on the `@Entity` and the matching fields on its `@IdClass` and tries to proceed either way.  This check can be found in the source [here](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/d2a19c9a7794df7e2f4367e8d86a9cda05a0d978/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/tuple/entity/AbstractEntityTuplizer.java#L285).

If the types on the PK match a `NormalMappedIdentifierValueMarshaller` is used to construct the PK identifier value.  If they don't it seems to make a best effort to proceed with the expressively named `IncrediblySillyJpaMapsIdMappedIdentifierValueMarshaller`.  It seems that from there the code is following a 'less well trodden' path with the mixed types - clearly the save works out, but there are surprises to be found later on.

Comment: interesting, tried your example, after more analyze, in SamplesPK, you use Sampling instead of SamplingsPK. if you use SamplingsPK, you will get the issue. actually when you use samplings you don't get any issue because you know use class who extends sampling...

Comment: Hmmm, nice analysis.  A quick look at the Hibernate code suggests you're on to something with the types for the foreign key in `SamplesPK`.  I've updated the answer above with a bit more detail on what's happening.

Comment: i gived you +100... that don't solve the issue... but you provided a nice answer and analysis...